# ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64 installation getting stuck

Tags: software-installation

I got the Ubuntu bootable USB created using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8.
When I try to boot from the same USB - It gets to the first screen and gives me the optin to install Ubuntu. After hitting Enter It does not do anything. Below is my computer config.

I am using "ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64" as It was recommended here in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Is this the reason my installation getting stuck and I should use the 32 bit version as my machine is 32 bit version?

[image]

Comment: can you run `uname -a` and show us the output

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is 32bit (as shown from windows properties). so definitely 64bit version of ubuntu will not work.

[image: windows properties]

Tip: *even if your computer was 64bit, and RAM is 2GB its not recommended to use 64bit version of ubuntu. to use 64bit version of ubuntu your computer must be 64bit type and RAM should be greater than 2GB*

Comment: The processor is a [32 bit system](http://ark.intel.com/products/27231/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2050-2M-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB), but I think the picture is only showing that the prior OS is 32 bit, not that the processor is.

Comment: @CharlesGreen yeah processor is 32bit and OS 32bit, i dont understand what you mean to say

Comment: It was not uncommon for computers to be shipped with 32 bit Win7, while the hardware was 64 bit capable.

Comment: @CharlesGreen how can you be sure that hardware is 64bit. you only gave me link of that processor it showed that its 32bit processor

Comment: I think that's what I was trying to say - sorry if I'm being garbled, I got up pretty early to do some family stuff.  The HW is 32 bit, but I think that you can't tell that from the graphics above.  Those graphics are basically a really fancy `uname -a`